# Docker container .NET C# WSMan is either not installed or unavailable for this system

Tags: c#, .net, docker, powershell, winrm

I am developing application that should run in the container and using WinRM for sunning PS commands on remote Windows host.

For that purpose I am using [`WSManConnectionInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.wsmanconnectioninfo?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0) that is part of the namespace `System.Management.Automation.Runspaces`.

Developing on my local Windows machine, everything works fine, connection through WinRM is established and working.

However, I need to run the application in container, my `Dockerfile` is standard, looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplicationTST.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./././WebApplicationTST.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "./WebApplicationTST.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./WebApplicationTST.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplicationTST.dll"]
```

Running the application in container gives me the following error:

```
System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException: This parameter set requires WSMan, and no supported WSMan client library was found. WSMan is either not installed or unavailable for this system.
 ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libpsrpclient' or one of its dependencies. 

   at System.Management.Automation.Remoting.Client.WSManNativeApi.WSManInitialize(Int32 flags, IntPtr& wsManAPIHandle)
   at System.Management.Automation.Remoting.Client.WSManClientSessionTransportManager.WSManAPIDataCommon..ctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.Remoting.Client.WSManClientSessionTransportManager.WSManAPIDataCommon..ctor()
   at System.Management.Automation.Remoting.Client.WSManClientSessionTransportManager..ctor(Guid runspacePoolInstanceId, WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo, PSRemotingCryptoHelper cryptoHelper, String sessionName)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.WSManConnectionInfo.CreateClientSessionTransportManager(Guid instanceId, String sessionName, PSRemotingCryptoHelper cryptoHelper)
   at System.Management.Automation.Remoting.ClientRemoteSessionDSHandlerImpl..ctor(ClientRemoteSession session, PSRemotingCryptoHelper cryptoHelper, RunspaceConnectionInfo connectionInfo, URIDirectionReported uriRedirectionHandler)
   at System.Management.Automation.Remoting.ClientRemoteSessionImpl..ctor(RemoteRunspacePoolInternal rsPool, URIDirectionReported uriRedirectionHandler)
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.ClientRunspacePoolDataStructureHandler.CreateClientRemoteSession(RemoteRunspacePoolInternal rsPoolInternal)
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.ClientRunspacePoolDataStructureHandler..ctor(RemoteRunspacePoolInternal clientRunspacePool, TypeTable typeTable)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Internal.RemoteRunspacePoolInternal.CreateDSHandler(TypeTable typeTable)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Internal.RemoteRunspacePoolInternal..ctor(Int32 minRunspaces, Int32 maxRunspaces, TypeTable typeTable, PSHost host, PSPrimitiveDictionary applicationArguments, RunspaceConnectionInfo connectionInfo, String name)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspacePool..ctor(Int32 minRunspaces, Int32 maxRunspaces, TypeTable typeTable, PSHost host, PSPrimitiveDictionary applicationArguments, RunspaceConnectionInfo connectionInfo, String name)
   at System.Management.Automation.RemoteRunspace..ctor(TypeTable typeTable, RunspaceConnectionInfo connectionInfo, PSHost host, PSPrimitiveDictionary applicationArguments, String name, Int32 id)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(RunspaceConnectionInfo connectionInfo, PSHost host, TypeTable typeTable, PSPrimitiveDictionary applicationArguments, String name)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(RunspaceConnectionInfo connectionInfo, PSHost host, TypeTable typeTable)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(PSHost host, RunspaceConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(RunspaceConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
```

I am trying to figure out how to fix this, or eventualy if it is feasible to run it like that in the container using `WSManConnectionInfo`. I have spend hours trying to identify how to resolve it. Any idea would be appreciated.